# How to display movies on a grid with code

Tags: python, video, media

I want to play a bunch of movies on a grid let's say of dimension (n, n), where each movie m_ij is an element of the grid. I would like to decide which movie is positioned where on the grid at each second, i.e. movies can switch positions over time. How would one start to do this? I'd preferably use Python, but am open to use another language if appropriate. Thanks a lot for any help, it's for an art project.

Comment: Check out https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you prefer Python but first think I can think of to achieve something like that easily would be through using this JavaScript library called [p5js](https://p5js.org/) or [processing](https://processing.org/) which is same library written in Java. It is very good for doing art with code kinda thing. 
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2C1hrJMwz0) is a video to give you the idea.
Anyways hope this helps. Cheers.